# Export PrimeNG table to Excel file (xlsx)

Tags: angular, spring, primeng

How can I export the table data in PrimeNG to an Excel file?

I know, on the PrimeNG site there is an example that explained that.
But the example only exports the visible table values to an excel file and I want the full table.

I get the table data with a rest call from a database.

Maybe there is better solution to handle this in the backend? (Spring)

Answer (score 0):

define a reference to p-table tag using #, example <p-table #dt> , then in    , in p-table tab , create a button with event  (click)="dt.exportCSV()" , but make sure that columns should be defined in .ts file instead of hard coding them in html file.

Comment: You responded to the question of how to export to CSV, not to XLSX, which is the Excel file format. Do you have a solution for Excel?